# Passing variable to an rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec2

I am fairly new to rspec test and I have an issue trying to test the location of a user. This a test to mock the behaviour of a country_code to block spam from specific zones.

Here is the code of my service :

```
class GeocodeUserAuthorizer
  def initialize(user_country_code:)
    @user_country_code = user_country_code
  end

  def authorize!
    user_continent = ISO3166::Country.new(user_country_code).continent

    if user_continent == 'Africa'
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the code of my spec file:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe GeocodeUserAuthorizer do
  context 'with a user connecting from an authorized country' do
    it { expect(GeocodeUserAuthorizer.new.authorize!(user_country_code: { "CA" })).to eql(true) }
  end
end
```

And here is the failure code:

> Failures:
>
> 1) GeocodeUserAuthorizer with a user connecting from an authorized
>   country 
>        Failure/Error: it { expect(GeocodeUserAuthorizer.new.authorize!(user_country_code: { "CA"
>   })).to eql(true) }
>        ArgumentError:
>          missing keyword: user_country_code
>        # ./app/services/geocode_user_authorizer.rb:2:in `initialize'
>        # ./spec/services/geocode_user_authorizer_spec.rb:16:in`new'
>        # ./spec/services/geocode_user_authorizer_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
>        # ./spec/spec_helper.rb:56:in`block (3 levels) in '
>        # ./spec/spec_helper.rb:56:in `block (2 levels) in '

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't call your class correctly, your constructor requires the country code.  Try this:

```
describe GeocodeUserAuthorizer do
  context 'with a user connecting from an authorized country' do
    it { expect(GeocodeUserAuthorizer.new(user_country_code: { "CA" })).authorize!).to eql(true) }
  end
end
```

Also you'll want to add an `attr_reader` for `user_country_code` in your class if you want `authorize!` to use it without the `@` symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so my test was too complicated and lacked separations. Here is a final version that works.

The test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe GeocodeUserAuthorizer do
  let(:geocode_authorizer) { GeocodeUserAuthorizer.new(country_code: country_code) }

  context 'with a user connecting from an unauthorized country' do
    let!(:country_code) { 'AO' }

    it { expect(geocode_authorizer.authorize!).to eql(false) }
  end

  context 'with a user connecting from an authorized country' do
    let!(:country_code) { 'CA' }

    it { expect(geocode_authorizer.authorize!).to eql(true) }
  end
end
```

The service:

```
class GeocodeUserAuthorizer
  def initialize(country_code:)
    @country_code = country_code
  end

  def authorize!
    check_country
  end

  protected

    def check_country
      user_continent = ISO3166::Country.new(@country_code).continent

      if user_continent == 'Africa'
        return false
      else
        return true
      end
    end
end
```